# Android - Kotlin Sealed class with Rxkotlin filter

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin2

Since sealed is like enum object so i decided to use sealed class for network response, were it contains success or failure if it is success it contains data else error message
Example

```
  sealed class Result {
            sealed class Success : Result() {
                data class F1(val data: Any) : Success()
                data class F2(val data: Any) : Success()
            }

            sealed class Error : Result() {
                data class F1(val error: Any) : Error()
                data class F2(val error: Any) : Error()
            }
        }
```

the above Result class has either Success or Failure

```
 getSomeDataFromService()
                .filter {
                    it is Result.Success.F1
                }
                .map { it: Result
                    /*
                    i face problem here,my need is F1 data class but what i
                     got is Result ,i know that i can cast here, 
                    but i am eager to know for any other solution other than casting  
                     */


                }

}
```

is there is any other solution ?
Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `getSomeDataFromService()` returns a `Single`, you should be able to utilize [Maybe.ofType()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#ofType-java.lang.Class-):

```
getSomeDataFromService()
    .toMaybe()
    .ofType(Result.Success.F1::class.java)
    .map {
        ...
    }
```

If `getSomeDataFromService()` returns an `Observable`, you can use `Observable.ofType()` directly.

Comment: yeah that's good, but what for the case if i want to check with multiple conditions ?

Comment: You could try to utilize some of the many `flatMap*()` operations. But you have to consider that the stream itself can only contain one type. If you're mapping to a single type only, it might be worth having the type-checks within the `map()` operation.